# In-app purchase multiple account conflict

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing, in-app, android-inapp-purchase

I have an application which have in-app purchase functionality

Now there are 3 users say A, B and C

A has login to play service so every purchase is going to be done by A's account.

Now B login in my app and does a purchase for product 1 and enjoy his product but playservice has kept record that A has purchased 1 number product.

Now C login in my app and tries to purchase product 1 but play service gives error that this product has already purchased as this time also the actual purchasing user will be play service logged in user that is A.

What is the best flow for this type of condition?

Please help.

Comment: Please don't use SMS shortcuts in stackoverflow questions.